# Update value where values from two columns match one column value?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to update my mysql table (cityTable) with the cityFull value in administrativeTable where the cityCode values match country and city in cityTable.

I believe this statement should work. Only part that I am missing is what to put in the ???? for cityCode. It is a bit complicated as it also has a period (.)

```
UPDATE cityTable INNER JOIN administrativeTable ON (?????????? = administrativeTable.cityCode) SET cityTable.cityFull = administrativeTable.cityFull;
```

**administrativeTable**

```
+----------+-----------+
| cityCode | cityFull  |
+----------+-----------+
| AU.Melb  | Melbourne |
| NZ.Auck  | Auckland  |
+----------+-----------+
```

**cityTable**

```
+---------+------+-----------+
| country | city | cityFull  |
+---------+------+-----------+
| AU      | Melb |           |
| NZ      | Auck |           |
+---------+------+-----------+
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the function [`CONCAT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat):

```
UPDATE cityTable c
INNER JOIN administrativeTable a 
ON CONCAT(c.country, '.', c.city) = a.cityCode 
SET c.cityFull = a.cityFull;
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sRbStLfCT4xtSBqshcNBKm/0).
Results:

```
| country | city | cityFull  |
| ------- | ---- | --------- |
| AU      | Melb | Melbourne |
| NZ      | Auck | Auckland  |
```

Comment: Fantastic thank you so much! Really appreciate you took the time to post a demo too :)